# ASP.NET TcpClient intranet

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, sockets, tcpclient

I'm developing an application in ASP.NET using Visual Basic, that have to connect to a Server in my private network.
The application must working only into my network (in future it can work on internet, too),
now I have a problem with TcpClient on ASP.NET: If I connect to the Server using an instance of `IPAddress`

```
Client = New TcpClient
Client.Connect(New IPAddress("192.168.1.12"), 6001)
```

the Socket try to connect to 176.64.116.11 (that's not my public IP Address...), else, if I connect to the server with a string that contains the local IP Address

```
Client = New TcpClient
Client.Connect("192.168.1.12", 6001)
```

the Socket connects succesfully but nothing responds to my command (with `NetworkStream.Write` and `Read`)
I try all of these in a Windows Application and all work succesfully.

Thanks to all
(I made any mistake in English? Ahaha, sorry :D)

PS. If you post me some code in C# don't worry, I can translate it

Comment: Similar question: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10935409/tcp-client-in-asp-net)

Answer (score 0):

`TcpClient` has various overloads, you can give it a `string` containing the ip address or an `IPAddress` object.

Also, use

```
IPAddress ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.12");
```

`IPAddress` does not contain a constructor that takes a `string`.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.connect.aspx

As for your transmission issue; disable firewalls. Try localhost first.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification to the parse of IPAddress class.
I disable the firewall on my PC where Web server running, but it doesn't work...
The 192.168.1.12 isn't my PC where the Web server are running.

I noticied that the TcpClient connects succesfully to the server because if I change the Address value in Client.Connect to another IP Address, it trown a SocketException. The 192.168.1.12 are working! But not receive my messages.

This is the code...
https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=AD8D7108F872B84B!5850&authkey=!AMUNEHxEx1cc-So

Thanks a lot!